# pdftk wrapper for Ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, rubygems, pdftk

There are several Ruby wrapper gems for pdftk. Among them, is there any gem that installs the pdftk binary automatically cross major OSs at installation of itself? I want to require it in a library, and I can manually install pdftk on my own machine, but I want to avoid the mess of the users of my library being required to manually install pdftk binary.

Comment: You and everyone else :)  Unfortunately, the dependencies are quite fragmented and appear to get more complex over time.  Good luck with this, though!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a native solution such as [CombinePDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf)...?

Depends on what you need, it might actually serve you better.